# Oracle stored procedure query like not working with cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am new to oracle and trying to create a stored procedure with the following pl/sql code.

What is wrong with the code?when i replace the searchString with hard code value of '1605%' then the query is executed but not with the variable.

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY MAT_INFO AS

  PROCEDURE mat_details(mat_id IN varchar, mat_cur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS

  searchString varchar2(700);
  BEGIN

    searchString := ''''||mat_id||'%''';
    OPEN mat_cur FOR SELECT mi.* FROM S_JAMM_MAT_INFO mi WHERE mi.MAT_ID LIKE searchString;
  END mat_details;

END MAT_INFO;
```

Can anyone help me what am i doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: did you try to debug the procedure, your procedure seems to be ok need to check value at runtime. Use TOAD or any other tool where you can debug. Use DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (searchstring) while debug

Comment: DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_Line('SELECT mi.* FROM S_JAMM_MAT_INFO mi WHERE mi.MAT_ID LIKE '|| searchString);  And i get the following output in the output window: SELECT mi.* FROM S_JAMM_MAT_INFO mi WHERE mi.MAT_ID LIKE '1605310%'

Comment: I am using oracle sql developer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using unnecessary quotes:

```
SQL> declare
  2      mat_id        varchar2(100) := 'X';
  3      searchString  varchar2(100) := ''''||mat_id||'%''';
  4      searchString2 varchar2(100) := ''||mat_id||'%';
  5      num number;
  6  begin
  7      select count(1)
  8      into num
  9      from dual
 10      where 'X' like searchString;
 11      --
 12      dbms_output.put_line('1. num= ' || num);
 13      --
 14      select count(1)
 15      into num
 16      from dual
 17      where 'X' like searchString2;
 18      --
 19      dbms_output.put_line('2. num= ' || num);
 20  end;
 21  /
1. num= 0
2. num= 1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Your double quoting could be useful if you would use a dynamic SQL, but in your static query it means that you are looking for a pattern containing quotes as part of the string to look for.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. When i run the query in the query window it works with 'test%' so i thought, i need extra quote in the stored procedure. how it works in stored procedure without additonal quote?

Comment: I would think this is the same as most other languages. If you want to specify an employee named 'SMITH' using a parameter `p_empname`, you'd write `where e.empname = p_empname` with no need to pack it with quoted quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY MAT_INFO AS
  PROCEDURE mat_details(
    i_mat_id  IN  varchar,
    mat_cur   OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
  )
  AS
  BEGIN
    OPEN mat_cur FOR
      SELECT *
      FROM   S_JAMM_MAT_INFO
      WHERE  MAT_ID LIKE i_mat_id || '%';
  END mat_details;
END MAT_INFO;
/
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to change the procedure like below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY MAT_INFO AS

  PROCEDURE MAT_DETAILS(MAT_ID IN VARCHAR, MAT_CUR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS

  SEARCHSTRING VARCHAR2(700);
  CURSOR MAT_CUR (SEARCHSTRING VARCHAR) IS 
    SELECT MI.* FROM S_JAMM_MAT_INFO MI WHERE MI.MAT_ID LIKE SEARCHSTRING;

  BEGIN


    FOR DATA IN MAT_CUR(MAT_ID)
    LOOP
        --YOUR CODE 
    END LOOP;

  END MAT_DETAILS;

END MAT_INFO;
```

Comment: The OP is returning the cursor not processing it in the procedure.