# Oracle like in the query only bringing if the pattern is one less than the search string

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql

I created a stored procedure in Oracle with the help from the following link.

Now the search works but only when the searchstring in like operator is one character less than the actual match. If i enter the exact value for the searchstring, it is not bringing back the results.

eg:-
mat_id = '160520004%'-> not getting any results for this

but mat_id = '16052000%' -> getting results.

What is wrong with the query?

[Oralce query in stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37569476/oracle-stored-procedure-query-like-not-working-with-cursor)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The only thing wrong with the example you posted is that it isn't using the LIKE operator. Instead of mat_id = '160520004%', you should use mat_id LIKE '160520004%'
The percent sign is a wildcard that means "zero or more characters", so it will return the results you're looking for when used with LIKE

Comment: i am using LIKE in the actual query. I have just mentioned the value of the variable here. And the link has got the stored procedure.